# SQLite not working in Symfony2

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony

I had a web application running fine in MySQL, but when I used SQLite I execute all commands, but the problem is tables of database always empty.

So, when sql request gives me this error :

> TableNotFoundException in AbstractSQLiteDriver.php line 58: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO project (Title_Project) VALUES (?)':
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: project

But when I cheek my databse in phpStorm I found the table :
[image]

this is data in the table

Answer (score 2):

check that you have following in config.yml

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_sqlite
        path:     "%database_path%"
```

in parameters.yml define database_path something like

```
parameters:
    database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/db/database.db3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the created data base in the root folder, copy and past under **web folder** did the trick, thank's guys.